# What is the reason for my model is performing good and bad regarding to how I prepared the dataset?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, dataset

I have a **shuffled** dataset called "train_sentences/ train_labels" for a NLP project. I am doing an experiment about what if I use 10 percent of data. While I was preparing the dataset firstly I tryed that:

```
sentences_size = int(len(train_sentences)*0.1)

train_sentences_10_percent = np.random.choice(train_sentences, size=sentences_size, replace=False)
train_labels_10_percent = np.random.choice(train_labels, size=sentences_size, replace=False)
len(train_sentences_10_percent), len(train_labels_10_percent)
```

I get approximately 40 percent accuracy with this dataset. Then I prepared dataset like so:

```
ten_percent_num = int(len(train_sentences)*0.1)
train_sentences_10_percent = train_sentences[:ten_percent_num]
train_labels_10_percent = train_labels[:ten_percent_num]
```

Then I get 80 percent accuracy with this dataset using exactyly the same model.

Why is that?

I checked everything again and again then could not find anything. Everything seems same. Model was same and the others were, too.I asked this question to Google Bard, but it gave me some useless answers. Maybe, it is about Numpy randomization, but ofcourse it is just an estimate. I need an answer that satisfy me.

Comment: There may be a possibility of your model getting overfit. I suggest you try evaluating the model on the train data and test data separately and comparing the results. In the second code snippet, the data has not been shuffled as in the case of the first snippet. If you need further assistance, request you to share the complete code , if it holds validity now. thank you.